# State not calculating numbers correctly - just stringing them together

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

So i feel like an idiot. Im getting numbers strung together instead of added from my state. I cant seem to solve it using normal update state methods.
Its for component that selects how many of an item to buy from an invintory. Everything worked when i had on the option to buy one at a time. Now i have added the 'puchaseAmount' state that should control it. and the quantity breaks and strings '010101010' if i try to buy 10 at a time. The same thing happens to the total items owned count. I feel im missing something simple and stupid lol

```
  const [quantityOwned, setQuantityOwned] = useState(0);  
const [purchaseAmount, setPurchaseAmount] = useState(10);

const productIndex = newArray.findIndex((p) => p.id === product.id);

  if (productIndex !== -1) {
    newArray[productIndex].quantity = newArray[productIndex].quantity +  purchaseAmount
    const newCost = newArray[productIndex].cost * increaseConstant;
    newArray.push({
      ...product,
      cost: newCost
    });
  } else {
    newArray.push({
      ...product,
      quantity: purchaseAmount,
    });
  }

  if (productType === 'items') {
    setPlayerCharacter({
      ...playerCharacter,
      items: newArray,
    });
  }

  // // Increase product cost
  const newCost = product.cost * 1.1;
  product.cost = newCost.toFixed(2);

  // PPC Product
  if (product.type === 'pointsPerClick') {
    // Assign current values

    let currentPointsPerClick = playerCharacter.pointsPerClick;
    let currentTotalScore = playerCharacter.totalScore;

    let newPointsPerClickValue = currentPointsPerClick + product.effect;
    let newTotalScore = currentTotalScore - product.cost;

    setQuantityOwned(quantityOwned + purchaseAmount); // This is the trouble
    // i tried also (prev => prev + purchaseAmount)

    let newTotalBuildingsOwned = playerCharacter.totalBuildingsOwned;
    let newTotalItemsOwned = playerCharacter.totalItemsOwned;

    if (productType === 'items') {
      const newNum = playerCharacter.totalItemsOwned + purchaseAmount;
      newTotalItemsOwned = newNum;
    }

    if (productType === 'buildings') {
      const newNum =
        playerCharacter.newTotalBuildingsOwned + purchaseAmount;
      newTotalBuildingsOwned = newNum;
    }

    setPlayerCharacter({
      ...playerCharacter,
      pointsPerClick: newPointsPerClickValue,
      totalScore: newTotalScore,
      totalItemsOwned: newTotalItemsOwned,
      totalBuildingsOwned: newTotalBuildingsOwned,
    });
  }
```

Comment: Share the output as well along with the entire component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are concatenating the `purchaseAmount` (which is a `string`) with the current value of `quantityOwned/totalItemsOwned/totalBuildingsOwned` (which is a `number`), resulting in a `string`.

You need to convert the `purchaseAmount` to a `number` using `Number()` or `parseInt()` before using it in your calculation.

```
setQuantityOwned(prev => prev + Number(purchaseAmount));
```